# Align matrices problem

Tags: formatting, align, matrices

I have an equation of matrices and I want to align the dimensions of the matrices below the equation of matrices. However, I produce something very ugly. Can someone advise how to make it look better or properly aligned ?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A
&
\begin{bmatrix}
&&\\
\vec{v}_1 & \cdots & \vec{v}_r \\
&&
\end{bmatrix}
&= &
\begin{bmatrix}
&&\\
\vec{u}_1 & \cdots & \vec{u}_r\\
&&
\end{bmatrix}
&
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1 &&\\
&\ddots&\\
&& \sigma_r
\end{bmatrix}
\\
(m \times n) & (n \times r) & & (m \times r) & (r \times r)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the message you want to pass to? The dimension compability or the vector structure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible solution using `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
  $A$
& $
   \begin{bmatrix}
              &        &           \\
    \vec{v}_1 & \cdots & \vec{v}_r \\
              &        &
   \end{bmatrix}$
& $=$
& $
   \begin{bmatrix}
              &        &           \\
    \vec{v}_1 & \cdots & \vec{v}_r \\
              &        &
   \end{bmatrix}$
& $
   \begin{bmatrix}
    \sigma_1 &        &          \\
             & \ddots &          \\
             &        & \sigma_r
   \end{bmatrix}$\\
& $(m \times n)(n \times r)$
&
& $(m \times r)$
& $(r \times r)$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: outputA]

**Update**

If you want to color an entire row or individual cells, you can do the following (see also [Highlighting in tabular environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155251/highlighting-in-tabular-environment)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color,colortbl}

\definecolor{ColorA}{rgb}{0.25,0.5,0.75}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
  \cellcolor{ColorA}\,$A$
& \cellcolor{ColorA}$
   \begin{bmatrix}
              &        &           \\
    \vec{v}_1 & \cdots & \vec{v}_r \\
              &        &
   \end{bmatrix}$
& \cellcolor{ColorA}$=$
& \cellcolor{ColorA}$
   \begin{bmatrix}
              &        &           \\
    \vec{v}_1 & \cdots & \vec{v}_r \\
              &        &
   \end{bmatrix}$
& \cellcolor{ColorA}$
   \begin{bmatrix}
    \sigma_1 &        &          \\
             & \ddots &          \\
             &        & \sigma_r
   \end{bmatrix}$\\
& $(m \times n)(n \times r)$
&
& $(m \times r)$
& $(r \times r)$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: outputB]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color,colortbl}

\definecolor{ColorA}{rgb}{0,1,1}
\definecolor{ColorB}{rgb}{1,0,1}
\definecolor{ColorC}{rgb}{1,1,0}
\definecolor{ColorD}{rgb}{0.25,0.5,0.75}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
  \cellcolor{ColorA}\,$A$\,
& \cellcolor{ColorB}$
   \begin{bmatrix}
              &        &           \\
    \vec{v}_1 & \cdots & \vec{v}_r \\
              &        &
   \end{bmatrix}$
& \,$=$\,
& \cellcolor{ColorC}$
   \begin{bmatrix}
              &        &           \\
    \vec{v}_1 & \cdots & \vec{v}_r \\
              &        &
   \end{bmatrix}$
& \cellcolor{ColorD}$
   \begin{bmatrix}
    \sigma_1 &        &          \\
             & \ddots &          \\
             &        & \sigma_r
   \end{bmatrix}$\\
& $(m \times n)(n \times r)$
&
& \,$(m \times r)$
& $(r \times r)$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: outputC]

Comment: Hi, one more question, How can I highlight the entire line of matrices using your code ?

Comment: @asd See updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use subscripts, but in this particular case, this approach doesn't look completely fine. A better option could be to take a more "wordy" approach. The following example shows both possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
A_{m\times n}
\begin{bmatrix}
&& \\
\vec{v}_1 & \cdots & \vec{v}_r \\
&&
\end{bmatrix}_{n\times r}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
&& \\
\vec{u}_1 & \cdots & \vec{u}_r\\
&&
\end{bmatrix}_{m\times r}
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1 &&\\
&\ddots&\\
&& \sigma_r
\end{bmatrix}_{r\times r}
\]

So we have
\[
AV=U\Sigma,
\]
where $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $V$, $U$ and $\Sigma$ are the $n\times r$, $m\times r$ and $r\times r$, respectively, matrices given by
\[
V=
\begin{bmatrix}
&& \\
\vec{v}_1 & \cdots & \vec{v}_r \\
&&
\end{bmatrix},\quad
U=
\begin{bmatrix}
&& \\
\vec{u}_1 & \cdots & \vec{u}_r\\
&&
\end{bmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad
\Sigma=
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1 &&\\
&\ddots&\\
&& \sigma_r
\end{bmatrix}.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An attempt with `\underset`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A \underset{\textstyle (m \times n) \, (n \times r)}{\begin{bmatrix}
&&\\
\vec{v}_1 & \cdots & \vec{v}_r \\
&&
\end{bmatrix}}
&= 
\underset{\textstyle (m \times r)}{\begin{bmatrix}
&&\\
\vec{u}_1 & \cdots & \vec{u}_r\\
&&
\end{bmatrix}}
\underset{\textstyle (r \times r)}{\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1 &&\\
&\ddots&\\
&& \sigma_r
\end{bmatrix}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is probably the best solution if no coloring is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\arraycolsep}{8pt}
\NiceMatrixOptions{nullify-dots, last-row, code-for-last-row = \color{black}}

\[
\color{blue}
A 
\begin{bNiceMatrix}
\\
\vec{v}_1 & \Cdots & \vec{v}_r \\
\\
\Block{1-3}{(m \times n)(n \times r)}
\end{bNiceMatrix}
=
\begin{bNiceMatrix}
\\
\vec{v}_1 & \Cdots & \vec{v}_r \\
\\
\Block{1-3}{(m \times r)}
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\begin{bNiceMatrix}
\sigma_1 \\
& \Ddots \\
& & \sigma_r 
\\
\Block{1-3}{(r \times r)} 
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the first code]

---

If you wish, you can add a background under the matrices with Tikz (by using the PGF/Tikz nodes created by `nicematrix` under the row, columns and cells of the matrices).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\arraycolsep}{8pt}
\NiceMatrixOptions{nullify-dots, last-row}

\[A 
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[name=A]
\\
\vec{v}_1 & \Cdots & \vec{v}_r \\
\\
\Block{1-3}{(m \times n)(n \times r)}
\end{bNiceMatrix}
=
\begin{bNiceMatrix}
\\
\vec{v}_1 & \Cdots & \vec{v}_r \\
\\
\Block{1-3}{(m \times r)}
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[name=B]
\sigma_1 \\
& \Ddots \\
& & \sigma_r 
\\
\Block{1-3}{(r \times r)} 
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\tikz [overlay, remember picture]
   \fill [red!15,blend mode = multiply] 
   (A-1-|A-1) ++ (-6pt,0pt) rectangle (B-4-|B-4) ; 
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]