# Highlighting in tabular environment

Tags: tables, matrices, highlighting

I am trying highlight a row of matrices in a tabular environment. However, the left brackets of the matrices are gone. And I don't know how to fix this.

In addition, how can I highlight 2 elements within a matrix, i.e. highlight "... & \vec{v}_n" ? How can this be done ? [image: picture]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, colortbl}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c}
\rowcolor{yellow}
$A$
&
$\begin{bmatrix}
&&&&\\
\vec{v}_1 &\cdots &\vec{v}_r & \cdots & \vec{v}_n\\
&&&&
\end{bmatrix}
$
&
$=$
&
$\begin{bmatrix}
&&&&\\
\vec{u}_1 &\cdots & \vec{u}_r & \cdots& \vec{u}_m\\
&&
\end{bmatrix}$
&
$
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1 &&&\\
&\ddots&&\\
&& \sigma_r&\\
&&&
\end{bmatrix}
$\\
$(m \times n)$
&
$(n \times n)$
&
&
$(m \times n)$
&
$(m \times n)$
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an interesting feature.....

`\cellcolor` works better (and by using `\cellcolor` on just some of the cells you can highlight smaller parts of the display)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, colortbl}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c}
\cellcolor{yellow}
$A$
&
\cellcolor{yellow}
$\begin{bmatrix}
&&&&\\
\vec{v}_1 &\cdots &\vec{v}_r & \cdots & \vec{v}_n\\
&&&&
\end{bmatrix}
$
&
\cellcolor{yellow}
$=$
&
\cellcolor{yellow}
$\begin{bmatrix}
&&&&\\
\vec{u}_1 &\cdots & \vec{u}_r & \cdots& \vec{u}_m\\
&&
\end{bmatrix}$
&
\cellcolor{yellow}
$
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1 &&&\\
&\ddots&&\\
&& \sigma_r&\\
&&&
\end{bmatrix}
$\\
$(m \times n)$
&
$(n \times n)$
&
&
$(m \times n)$
&
$(m \times n)$
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

You can use `\cellcolor` also on the nested matrix:

```
&
\cellcolor{yellow}
$\begin{bmatrix}
&&&&\\
\vec{u}_1 &\cdots &\cellcolor{blue} \vec{u}_r & \cdots& \vec{u}_m\\
&&
\end{bmatrix}$
&
```

Comment: What about adding a different color onto specific elements of  a matrix ?

Comment: *feature*, you say? :-)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13316878#13316878

Comment: @asd just use `\cellcolor` again. I added an example to the end of my answer.

Comment: BTW, did you discover anything about this *feature*?

Comment: @karlkoeller well I know more or less what's happening (which is why I guessed `\cellcolor` would work) but haven't had time to look at the sources, and my cunning plan of raising it on chat so egreg would fix it for me failed :(